# how to handle shouldChangeCharactersIn for a TextField, if it is located in the Custom Cell in the TabelViewControler

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I can not understand. How to do it, tried this:

```
class myViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var myEdit: UITextField!
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            // don`t work ((
        }
    }

class myTableViewControler: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NamePhoneCell", for: indexPath) as! myViewCell
            …
        returns cell
    }
}
```

I had an idea - Delegete. But how, I need to delegate the -shouldChangeCharactersIn method, which UITableViewCell itself delegates from UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: have you assigned the textfield delegate of myEdit to cell?

Comment: I wanted, but UITebleViewCell did not override the viewDidLoad() method

Comment: yes, UITableViewCell does not override viewDidLoad() method. you have to override the awakeFromNib() method and do all the initialisations there, like setting the delegate for textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate for your UITextField that you create. 
myViewCell will be implementing the delegate function of your UITextField.

```
class myViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var myEdit: UITextField!
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            // don`t work ((
        }
    }


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    myEdit.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign UITextField delegate to myViewCell

Add into `myViewCell` class next:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    myEdit.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: oh-oh, thank you, I did not understand how, but it works. I hope I understand the delegation in the future.